# Google Cloud SQL Incorrect Key File

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

On several occasions, I've tried to do a query on Google Cloud SQL that involves an `order by` statement, only to have the query fail with the error

```
Incorrect key file for table '/cloudsqltmp/#sql_44f4_1.MYI'; try to repair it
```

This sounds like the /cloudsqltmp/ partition is filling up with my temporary table. The result set isn't that big, however, and the program doing that query has done so on several other occasions, so I suspect that the space is actually filling up with someone else's temporary table. I was able to clear this by restarting the instance several times (I assume it finally gave me a new machine, or the space cleared up), but this seems very inelegant.

1. Is there a better way to handle this if it happens again?
2. Is there a better way to prevent this from happening?
3. If my assumption of what happened is wrong - what actually happened?

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend doing is:

Creating a Google Compute Engine instance and run MySQL on it. This way if you run into this problem again, you can use the follow solution below.

1) Modify the /tmp partition to have more space. There is a very useful [link here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1431169&s=01ecd9726e43b8b4498f63fcc929341f&p=8976725#post8976725) on how to do it.

2) Create a CronJob to clear the /tmp. If you are not comfortable with CronJob, I found another tool called [tmpreaper](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/tmpreaper.8.html). To install it, run `sudo apt-get install tmpreaper`. Also use InnoDB instead of MyISIAM. Google recommends [using it](https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#tools).

3) You are correct to assume that /tmp is getting full since restarting the instance resolves the issue

I hope my recommendations were helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately, Cloud SQL is managed by Google, so I don't have control over /tmp myself. So while this may be valid for MySQL installations whwer you have access to cron and the file system, it isn't valid in this case unfortunately

Comment: I would recommend switching to InnoDB tables. Google website mentions to use as you might run into performance issues on MySIAM. Also, looking at this post on the MySQL [website](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/corrupted-myisam-tables.html). The comments at the bottom mention that changing to InnoDB resolved the issue.

Comment: Re: InnoDB. As the link you suggested points out, InnoDB tables are the default. I suspect that, since these are internal temporary tables being created, it is using MyISAM and there is no way to control this.